# Pointer syntax usage in Array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I have some problem understanding the pointers syntax usage in context with two dimensional arrays, though I am comfortable with 1-D array notation and pointers, below is one of the syntax and I am not able to understand how the following expression is evaluated.

To access the element stored at **third row second column** of array **a** we will use the subscripted notation as  **a[2][1]** other way to access the same element is

```
*(a[2]+1)
```

and if we want to use it as pointers we will do like this

```
*(*(a+2)+1)
```

Though I am able to understand the replacement of `*(a[2]+1)`
as  `*(*(a+2)+1)` but I don't know how this is getting evaluated.
Please explain with example if possible.
Assume array is stored in row wise order and contain the following elements

```
int a[5][2]={
               21,22,
               31,32
               41,42,
               51,52,
               61,62
             };
```

and base address of array is **100(just assume)** so the address of **a[2]** is **108 (size of int =2(another assumption))** So the expression `*(*(a+2)+1). How does it gets evaluated does it start from the inside bracket and if it does then after the first bracket we have the value to which 1 is being added rather than the address... :/`

Comment: For any array `x`, the expression `x[i]` is identical to `*(x + i)`. Take it from there, considering that `x[i]` may itself be an array.

Comment: Din't you get any duplicates of this question? It might already have an elaborated answer, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start of with

```
a[i] = *(a+i);
```

So

```
a[i][j] = *(a[i] +j)
```

and

```
a[i][j] = *(*(a+i) + j)
```

> How a[i] = *(a+i):

If `a` is a array then the starting address of the array is given by `&a[0]` or just `a`

So when you specify

`a[i]` this will decay to a pointer operation `*(a+i)` which is, start at the location `a` and dereference the pointer to get the value stored in the location.

If the memory location is `a` then the value stored in it is given by `*a`.

Similarly the address of the next element in the array is given by

```
&a[1] = (a+1); /* Array decays to a pointer */
```

Now the location where the element is stored in given by `&a[1]` or `(a+1)` so the value stored in that location is given by `*(&a[1])` or `*(a+1)`

For Eg:

```
int a[3];
```

They are stored in the memory as shown below:

```
  a    a+1   a+2
------------------
| 100 | 102 | 104| 
------------------
 &a[0] &a[1] &a[2]
```

Now a is pointing to the first element of the array. If you know the pointer operations `a+1` will give you the next location and so on.

In 2D arrays the below is what the access is like :

```
int arr[m][n];



  arr:
        will be pointer to first sub array, not the first element of first sub 
        array, according to relationship of array & pointer, it also represent 
        the array itself,

    arr+1:
        will be pointer to second sub array, not the second element of first sub 
        array,

    *(arr+1):
        will be pointer to first element of second sub array,
        according to relationship of array & pointer, it also represent second
        sub array, same as arr[1],

    *(arr+1)+2:
        will be pointer to third element of second sub array,

    *(*(arr+1)+2):
        will get value of third element of second sub array,
        same as arr[1][2],
```

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned in the question, Though I am able to understand the replacement of *(a[2]+1) as *(*(a+2)+1) but I don't know how this is getting evaluated. Please explain with example if possible

Comment: @Karan Check the edits and let me know whether it helped or not

Comment: @Karan Hmmmm. I have explained what I could take a look

Comment: The sub-expression *(a+2) in *(*(a+2)+1) will give a value rather than an address rt. So how come a *(value+1) will give the another value..?

Comment: @Karan In 2D space you a double pointer `int **a;` then `*a` will be a pointer you get it?

Comment: Hey Gopi I was going through your answer I have the follwing doubts           1)arr:
        will be pointer to first sub array, not the first element of first sub 
        array, according to relationship of array & pointer, it also represent 
        the array itself,                                                                                                    Well the first element happens to be present at the location of the first sub-array so Why you have mentioned it explicitly that it doesnot point to the first element of the first sub-array Indirectly it points only to it rt ?

Comment: And also arr+1:
        will be pointer to second sub array, not the second element of first sub 
        array,

    *(arr+1):
        will be pointer to first element of second sub array,
        according to relationship of array & pointer, it also represent second
        sub array, same as arr[1],                                                                       Isn't the value at both the above location is the same ?

Answer (score 4):

A 2D array is actually a consecutive piece of memory. Let me take a example : `int a[3][4]` is representend in memory by a unique sequence of 12 integer :

```
a00 a01 a02 a03 a04 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 a20 a21 a22 a23 a24
|                   |                   |
first row           second row          third row
```

(of course it can be extended to any muti-dimensional array)

`a` is an array of `int[4]` : it *decays* to a pointer to `int[4]` (in fact, it decays to `&(a[0])`)

`a[1]` is second row. It *decays* to a `int *` pointing to beginning of first row.

Even if arrays are not pointer, the fact that they  decay to pointers allows to use them in pointer arithmetic : `a + 1` is a pointer to second element of array a.

All that explains why `a[1] == *(a + 1)`

The same reasoning can be applied to `a[i] == *(a+i)`, and from there to all the expressions in your question.

Let's look specifically to `*(*(a+2)+1)`. As said above, `a + 2` is a pointer to the third element of an array of `int 4`. So `*(a + 2)` is third row, is an array of `int[4]` and decays to a `int *` : `&(a[2][0])`.

As `*(a + 2)` decays to an `int *`, we can still use it as a base for pointer arithmetic and `*(a + 2) + 1` is a pointer to the second element of third row : `*(a + 2) + 1 == &(a[2][1])`. Just dereference all that and we get

```
*(*(a + 2) + 1) == a[2][1]
```

Comment: Check my comment in the above answer